# wallaby.js with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, wallaby.js

We are using wallaby.js in an Angular 4 project with typescript and there are some parts using jQuery. Wallaby.js is throwing a ReferenceError:

```
​​ReferenceError: $ is not defined​​
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Some Sample code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FroalaService {

  constructor() { }
  public initFroala(): void {
    $.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('insertnonbreakingspace', {NAME: 'arrows-h'});
    $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('insertnonbreakingspace', {
      title: 'Non-Breaking Space',
      focus: true,
      undo: true,
      refreshAfterCallback: true,
      callback: function () {
        this.html.insert('<span style="white-space: nowrap;"> </span>');
      }
    });
    $.FroalaEditor.RegisterShortcut(32, 'insertnonbreakingspace', null, 'Space', false, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Include whatever code defines `$`

Comment: There are other parts too, but I cannot change the code, I have to adjust the  wallaby config somehow.

Comment: 1) Wallaby.js is throwing an error or your sample code when trying to use that module as part of jQuery?  2) How are you including jQuery in your project?  Are you trying to package it or just include it as a script tag?

Comment: 1) wallaby is throwing the error, the application and the test with karma are working fine. 2) jquery is included as package in package.json

Comment: It is fine that it is in package.json, but is it in angular.json or loaded with script tags in html?  Either way, the only thing I could think of is that jquery is being loaded after wallaby and that Wallaby calls on jQuery immediately.  Can you confirm the order they are loading in?

Comment: jquery is loading in the scripts section within angular.json as the first entry "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js". There is no order for loading wallaby and jquery anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that wallaby was a test framework.  I was just looking at some examples and saw that a reference to jquery is added to the wallaby configuration file in the files section.  Maybe add that?

Comment: I found a solution, but now I have the problem to access the FroalaEditor wihtin $. For VS Code all is fine but wallaby says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'DefineIcon' of undefined​​"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for a basic jQuery implemention is to add jQuery to externals in wallaby.js:

```
var webpackPostprocessor = wallabyWebpack({
    entryPatterns: [
      'src/wallabyTest.js',
      'src/**/*spec.js'
    ],

    module: {
      rules: [
        ...
      ]
    },

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
      modules: [
       ...
      ]
    },
    node: {
      ...
    },
    externals: { jQuery: "jQuery" }
  });
```

...and to add jquery.js to files:

```
return {
    files: [
      {pattern: "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", instrument: false},
      {pattern: 'src/**/*.+(ts|css|less|scss|sass|styl|html|json|svg)', load: false},
      {pattern: 'src/**/*.d.ts', ignore: true},
      {pattern: 'src/**/*spec.ts', ignore: true}
    ],
    ...
```